# Difficulties in evaluating mpmath gammainc function

Tags: python, numerical-integration, mpmath, gamma-function

I am playing with the python library mpmath, in particular evaluating the incomplete gamma function.
This is part of a root finding routine but its evaluation is extremely slow for some combinations of complex-valued arguments.

```
import mpmath as mp
from mpmath import gammainc
def Gamma(a,z0,z1):
    return gammainc(a,a=z0,b=z1,regularized=False)
```

Here the evaluation of the `mpmath.gammainc` function gets stuck:

```
>> Gamma(mp.mpc(12.5+17.5j), mp.mpf(0.0), mp.mpf(-12.5))
```

On the other hand, Mathematica returns me the result almost instantly:

```
In[1]:= Gamma[12.5 + 17.5 I, 0, -12.5]
Out[1]:= 2.38012*10^-7 + 5.54827*10^-7 I
```

In other cases, for different arguments `mpmath` and `Mathematica` return the same output:

*Mathematica*

```
In[2]: Gamma[3.5 I, 0, 10]
Out[2]:= 0.0054741 + 0.000409846 I
```

*Python mpmath*

```
>> Gamma(3.5j,0,10)
mpc(real='0.0054741038497352953', imag='0.00040984640431357779')
```

Do you have some idea of the reason of this behaviour? Can this be considered a problem of `mpmath` or is this a mathematical problem of  quadrature?
Unfortunately `scipy` does not offer an implementation of `gamma` functions for complex arguments, so it not an option.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, a bug in mpmath causes it to go into an infinite loop when evaluating `gammainc` in some cases. Worth reporting on the [mpmath tracker](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath/issues). But at least for the case you mentioned, a workaround is to write the three-argument incomplete gamma function as the difference of two *upper* incomplete gamma functions ([reference](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma3/27/02/0001/)). The upper incomplete gamma function is computed by passing *two* arguments to `gammainc` (i.e., `z1` is implicitly taken to be positive infinity).

```
def Gamma(a, z0, z1):
    return gammainc(a, z0) - gammainc(a, z1)

print(Gamma(12.5+17.5j, 0.0, -12.5))
```

prints `(2.3801203496987e-7 + 5.54827238374855e-7j)` in agreement with WolframAlpha.

Comment: Can you say why you think it's infinite recursion? Perhaps a source link, if you've identified where the code goes wrong? I would expect such infinite recursion to overflow the stack and crash relatively quickly.

Comment: If I try to evaluate `gammainc(12.5+17.5j, 0.0, -12.5)` and interrupt the computation after a while, the stack trace consists mostly of three lines:  "expintegrals.py, line 163, expintegrals.py, line 166, expintegrals.py, line 241", repeated over and over again. Maybe an infinite loop rather than recursion.

Comment: After trying it out, it's definitely recursion (though I don't know whether it's theoretically infinite), and it hits the recursion limit pretty quickly.